# Generic function for all text boxes in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net

I have written a function for validating numeric input in a text field i.e., "txtDiaThick". How can i make this function generic so it can handle all numeric fields? For example how can i make "txtDiaThick.Focus()" generic?

Here is the code.

```
Private Sub txtDiaThick_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles txtDiaThick.Validating

        If Not IsNumeric(txtDiaThick.Text) And txtDiaThick.Text <> String.Empty Then
            MessageBox.Show("Diameter must be numeric")
            e.Cancel = True
            txtDiaThick.Focus()
            Exit Sub
 End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’d use the `sender` argument, which represents the control that raised the event:

```
Private Sub NumericTextBox_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles txtDiaThick.Validating, …
    Dim numericTextBox As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)

    If numericTextBox.Text <> String.Empty AndAlso Not IsNumeric(numericTextBox.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Diameter must be numeric")
        e.Cancel = True
        numericTextBox.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
```

Consider using a control dedicated to numbers if appropriate, though.

Comment: It worked for me except i had to change the type of numericTextBox from TextBox to System.Windows.Forms.Control. Don't know why but problem solved. Thanks